# How to disable copy in PowerBi embedded report

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

[image]

How do you disable copy value and copy selection in an embedded report?

I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/change-visual-commands#customize-menu-commands) documentation.

This is my extension

```
extensions: {
                        commands: [
                            {
                                name: 'copy',
                                displayOption: models.CommandDisplayOption.Disabled
                            },
                            {
                                name: 'clearSelection',
                                displayOption: models.CommandDisplayOption.Disabled
                            }
                        ]
                    }
```

Can someone please help?

EDIT:
I'm using 'powerbi-client-react' in my code to embed my report.

```
import { PowerBIEmbed } from 'powerbi-client-react';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be:

```json
{
 commands: [
 {
   copy: {
     displayOption: models.CommandDisplayOption.Disabled
   }
 }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using `updateSettings` method of JavaScript API:

```
var report = powerbi.get(reportContainer);

report.updateSettings({
  settings: {
    panes: {
      copy: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Here is the screenshot of the result. https://imgur.com/Fh65OYw code: https://imgur.com/fbydo2z